# How to change enctype to 'multipart/form-data' in joomla 2.5.9 registration page?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have trying since a few days to change the enctype in joomla registration page. I am not a pro at Joomla. I edited

> components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php

and added the enctype attribute to the form line as, so now it looks like this:

```
    <form id="member-registration" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo
    JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.register'); ?>"
    method="post" class="form-validate" >
```

However, the change is not being reflected on the user side :(.

I want to change the enctype to multipart/form-data to allow image uploads via Profile Picture plugin. I tried using K2 registration form as well, but with no success. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your template probably has an override for the output. Have a look at the file in `/templates/yourtemplate/com_users/registration/default.php`

Some doc about template overrides can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core